# Joining two models in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model stored in a variable like:

```php
$user = User::where('name', 'like', $test)
    ->orderBy('name');
```

I would like to build another query where I can join `$user`. Can't find the right syntax to do it.

What am trying to achieve:

```
$numbers= Number::join($user, $users.id, '=', 'number.user_id')
    ->where('name', 'like', "%" . $validated['text'] . "%")])
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do, and what attempts you've made to solve the problem?

Comment: @miken32 I edited my question

Comment: Are you saying you want to select numbers with certain name, that are attached to users with certain name? What relationships are set up between `User` and `Number` models?

Comment: @miken32 yes. Users have an ID and Number have a user_id column

Comment: Please post your model relationships.

Comment: It is not recommended to use a `join` to get related models. You should be using [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have typical `hasMany`/`belongsTo` relationships set up between `User` and `Number` models, this should work:

```php
User::where("name", "like", $test)
    ->whereHas("numbers", function($q) {
        $q->where("name", "like", "%$validated[text]%");
    })
    ->with("numbers", function($q) {
        $q->where("name", "like", "%$validated[text]%");
    })
    ->get();
```

The `where()` method, of course, matches users with the desired name. The `whereHas()` method [further restricts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) based on the relationship, looking only for users having numbers with a matching name. Assuming you want to retrieve those matching numbers, you have to do the same filter again on the [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: so what is the purpose of the with function? Also, does `$q` represent the other model (`$numbers`)?

Comment: `with()` loads the numbers that are related, as explained in the documentation I linked to. Otherwise if you get them later you'll be causing another database query. Eager loading reduces how many queries you do against the database.

Comment: And `$q` is the query object that the `whereHas` or `with` function uses in the background to do the database query.

Comment: So there is no way I can just use the $users variable in my second query?

Comment: You don't need a second query. The whole point of Eloquent is that you don't use Query Builder at all, because you properly define your models' relationships. You may be able to get something working with subqueries? I don't know, because this sort of thing is usually more easily done with Eloquent, as in the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$numbers= Number::whereHas('<Your Eloquent Model>',function($query)use($validated){
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%" . $validated['text'] . "%")]);
}    
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Join can be written in this way

```
$records = User::select('users.*')
    ->where('users.name', 'like', $test)
    ->join('numbers', function($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'numbers.id')
             ->where('numbers.name', 'like', "%" . $validated['text'] . "%");
    })
    ->get();
```